# How do you identify a specific Frame ID and inject content into its Body?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My goal is to insert a string (append) to existing content in an iFrame through various user actions in my Chrome Extension.

The decision to insert/inject a string will be made by a content.js script running on the page and all its iframes. The code of the CS is below.

Using activeElement doesn't get me the ID of a frame (it does get htmlarea, input).

Here is code from my content.js file that picks up the activeElement ID & tag...

```
var activeEl = null;
var activeTag = null;
var activeID = null;

document.addEventListener('focusin',function(event){
  console.log('Detected a focusin...')
  activeEl = document.activeElement;
  activeTag = activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase();
  activeID = activeEl.id;
  console.log("focusin and type of element is: " + activeEl.id + " / " + activeTag);
});
```

background.js sends a message to content.js with the text to insert at the cursor location:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      console.log("Made it to message receiver in content.js with request: ") + console.log(request);

    if (request.method == 'insertComment'){
      insertAtCursor(request.comment);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Message didn\'t come from insertText...');
    }
});
```

**insertAtCursor** processes based on the type of Element. If it's an iFrame I don't have a process to insert the value at the cursor position - I just message the user with an alert and stuff the text into the clipboard:

```
function insertAtCursor(sValue) {

  console.log('Starting insert routine...');

  var currentEl = document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase();      //Checking for currently selected area

//Need to take into account 2 scenarios:
  // 1) Google Docs, where the last Element will be iFrame but we've opened a simple textarea in the form of a bubble that won't show as active (clicked) area
  // 2) HTML editors that have been changed to plain text...which will not have empty objects for cilcked/keypunched area.

  console.log("currentEl before logic: " + currentEl + " / " + document.activeElement.id);
  console.log("activeTag: " + activeTag);


  if (activeTag === undefined || activeTag === null){
    console.log('currentEl in logic: ' + currentEl);
    if (currentEl === 'iframe'){
      activeTag = 'iframe';
      console.log('Making activeTag equal iframe');
    }
  }

  var sField = activeEl;
  /
  if (activeTag === 'input' || activeTag === 'textarea'){
    // console.log('Dealing with plain input/textarea - yes!');

    try {
      var nStart = sField.selectionStart;
      var nEnd = sField.selectionEnd;
    }
      catch (e) {
       //statements to handle any exceptions
       console.log("Can't grab start and end...")
        sField.value = sValue;
    }

     if (nStart || nEnd == '0'){
        // console.log("Inside insert sub with starting point: " + nStart + ' and end ' + nEnd + ' with value ' + sValue);

        sField.value = sField.value.substring(0, nStart) + sValue + sField.value.substring(nEnd, sField.value.length);
        sField.selectionStart = nStart + sValue.length;
        sField.selectionEnd = nStart + sValue.length;
       }
    else {
      sField.value = sValue;
    }
  }

  else if (activeTag === "div"){
    // console.log('We know you are a div...');
    var sel, range;
        if (window.getSelection) {
            // IE9 and non-IE
            sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                range.deleteContents();

                var el = document.createElement("div");
                el.innerHTML = sValue;
                var frag = document.createDocumentFragment(), node, lastNode;
                while ( (node = el.firstChild) ) {
                    lastNode = frag.appendChild(node);
                }
                var firstNode = frag.firstChild;
                range.insertNode(frag);

                // Preserve the selection
                if (lastNode) {
                    range = range.cloneRange();
                    range.setStartAfter(lastNode);
                    // if (selectPastedContent) {
                        range.setStartBefore(firstNode);
                    // } else {
                    //     range.collapse(true);
                    // }
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);
                }
            }
        } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
            // IE < 9
            var originalRange = sel.createRange();
            originalRange.collapse(true);
            sel.createRange().pasteHTML(sValue);
            // if (selectPastedContent) {
                range = sel.createRange();
                range.setEndPoint("StartToStart", originalRange);
                range.select();
            }
        }

  else if (activeTag === "iframe" ){

    //try using current activeElement...
    console.log('iFrame, Body, or Button...' + window.location.href);


    if (currentEl === 'iframe') {

      $('#' + activeID).contents().find('div').html(sValue);

      console.log('Not a textarea, input, or editable div - iframe with ID: ' + activeID);
      alert("This message is from Annotate PRO: \n\nWe can't insert text into an this sort of input area (an iFrame) - sorry! \n\nIf you can, change the editor to TEXT ONLY and try again.\n\nAs a workaround, we've copied your selected Comment into the clipboard, so you could just PASTE that bad boy in there right now and be done with it!");
      console.log('Try to use clipboard...');

      const input = document.createElement('input');
      input.style.position = 'fixed';
      input.style.opacity = 0;
      input.value = sValue;
      document.body.appendChild(input);
      input.select();
      document.execCommand('Copy');
      document.body.removeChild(input);

    }   //End check for iFrame

  }   //End iframe

  else if (activeTag === "body" || activeTag === "button"){

    var sField = document.activeElement;
    try {
      var nStart = sField.selectionStart;
      var nEnd = sField.selectionEnd;
    }
      catch (e) {
       // statements to handle any exceptions
      //  console.log("Can't grab start and end...")
        sField.value = sValue;
    }

    if (nStart || nEnd == '0'){
      // console.log("Inside insert sub with starting point: " + nStart + ' and end ' + nEnd + ' with value ' + sValue);

      sField.value = sField.value.substring(0, nStart) + sValue + sField.value.substring(nEnd, sField.value.length);
      sField.selectionStart = nStart + sValue.length;
      sField.selectionEnd = nStart + sValue.length;
     }
    else {
       sField.value = sValue;
     }
    }   //End Else for non-iFrame. Made need to add more conditions here or make a subroutine

  // }


}   //End insertAtCursor
```

I believe I can use chrome.tabs.executeScript to inject into a specific iFrame, but I'm not sure of syntax or how to get the frameId.

Any help appreciated.

Manifest file (I edited some of the account numbers...not sure how sensitive they are):

```
{

"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "Annotate PRO for Chrome",
"short_name": "Annotate PRO",
"description": "Right-click access to a pre-written library of comments. Write it once, to perfection, and reuse forever!",
"version": "3.1.0.5",

"permissions": ["identity",
    "identity.email",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/",
    "clipboardWrite",
    "clipboardRead",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage", 
    "webNavigation",
    "*://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"],

"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",

"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": ["http://*.11trees.com/*"]},

    "commands": {
      "_execute_browser_action": {
        "suggested_key": {
          "windows": "Alt+A",
          "mac": "Alt+A",
          "chromeos": "Alt+A",
          "linux": "Alt+A"
        }
      }
    },

"key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsjrzouXmcjbWUKDjv5P/YMC0Ar57tk04MS2lSOW1V+SWqvck1iuJmUxW3PXHDrfdsNP2xnAB+wI7Qy9fM7VW95ELgRGcUnynk43WvZ1PtLV/QTTnYhFbIblaJcFmiVo48jpX9V6NaanjfYkpKwUXiM67vmvVNDftGz0wIDAQAB",

"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "4254-smaehlatsj3jmlrrecm.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly"
    ]
  },

"background": {"scripts": ["/dscripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js","/scripts/background.js", "/scripts/buy.js", "/scripts/contextMenus.js", "/scripts/accountChrome.js"]},


"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; object-src 'self'",


"content_scripts": [
    {
    "all_frames" : true,
    "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js": ["/scripts/content.js"]
    }
],

 "icons": {
          "16": "icon.png",
          "48": "icon.png",
          "128": "icon.png"
        },

"browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
        "19": "icon.png",
        "38": "icon.png"
    },
    "default_title": "Annotate PRO for Google Chrome",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
}

}
```

**Update**
With Makyen's help I have the content script successfully messaging background.js:

```
//Message background.js
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'injectTheAdditionalScript'});
```

I tweaked the provided code to make it work...and I'm able to get the console.log messages showing in the sending page and also see the frameId in the background.js console.log.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log('In Background and received message from iFrame...' + sender.tab.id + ' / ' + sender.frameId);
    if(typeof message === 'object' && message.type === 'injectTheAdditionalScript') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id,{
          frameId: sender.frameId,
          code: "\
                  console.log('Injecting a console log...');\
                  console.log('2nd line injecting a console log...');\
                  iframe.contentDocument.write('Hello world...');\
                "
        });
        // chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id,{
        //     frameId:sender.frameId,
        //     // file:'theAdditionalScript.js'
        //     {code: "console.log('Background.js injecting a script...')";
        // });
    }
});
```

Now I just have to figure out how to use that frameId to inject more than just console.log into the sending page:)

Comment: Please add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, we have to make significant assumptions regarding what you desire. For instance, some example HTML and some JavaScript showing what information you have already obtained (e.g. a reference to the `<iframe>`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for taking a look...I added some of the code...My manifest does have ** "all_frames" : true** set...so I can see all the layers to the page.

Comment: FYI: Using `all_frames` in a *manifest.json* `content_scripts` entry makes it so that the content script is injected into frames that match the URL, even if that frame is not the top level frame. It does not inject into all frames contained within a frame that matches the URL criteria, unless the contained frame also matches the URL criteria. This is not the same as what happens by using [`allFrames:true`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-details-allFrames) in `tabs.executeScript()`, which does inject into all frames contained in the tab.

Comment: Please add your *manifest.json* and make it more clear what is in the background script and what is in the content script. Please don't split off different functions into separate code blocks if they are actually contained in the same file.

Comment: It's not clear to me in what code you are trying to make the choice that you are wanting to inject a script into an iframe.  Are you making this choice from within a script that is already running in that iframe? Are you making that choice from the background script? From a content script in the top level frame?

Comment: Hi Makyen,

My background file has a ton of stuff...

Comments are inserted by a contextMenu onClicked event OR action in the popup.html.

Either path results in a message to the content.js script.

In my simplistic world, since I know when the cursor is in an iFrame, I'd be able to grab the iFrame's ID and do some sort of script execution to append content - so another option in content.js to go along with htmlarea etc.

Comment: We don't need a ton of stuff, just a minimal, but complete (it duplicates the problem) [mcve].

Comment: It seems like a focused, academic question: if you know you're in an iFrame (which I already do), how do you then get a script to run in that iFrame and append text?

Comment: But, in what context is the script running which is making the choice that something else needs to be injected (see earlier comment)? Is it a content script (CS) that is already running in the frame in which an injection needs to happen? Is it a CS in the top level frame? Is it in a script in the background context (e.g. background script, popup page script, options page script, etc.)? The answer is different for each of these, with the easiest (which may apply here) being that the choice is made in a CS which is already running in the iframe which needs an additional script injected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142221/discussion-between-11treeswriting-and-makyen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From our [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142221/discussion-between-11treeswriting-and-makyen), I was under the impression that you desired to inject an additional script into the frame in which the content script is running. However, it may be that you desire to get some text, or HTML, from your background script.

In both of these cases, the interaction between the content script and background script is initiated by the content script that is running in the iframe in which you want the data, or the additional script injected. In such cases, you either can get the `frameId` from the `sender` of the initial message sent by the content script, or you don't need to know the `frameId`.

### Injecting a script

You have stated that the choice to inject an *additional* script is being made from the content script in the iframe in which you want the additional script to be injected.  In that case, you can just [`runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage) to the background script. Then, the background script can inject the additional script into the frame from which the message was sent. The [`frameId`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-MessageSender-frameId) is part of the data structure provided in the [`sender`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-onMessage-sender).

To do so, you could so something like:

Content script:

```js
//Tell the background script to inject the additional script
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'injectTheAdditionalScript'});
```

Background script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(typeof message === 'object' && message.type === 'injectTheAdditionalScript') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(sender.tab.id,{
            frameId:sender.frameId,
            file:'theAdditionalScript.js'
        });
    }
});
```

### Getting some data (text)

With the interaction initiated by the content script, if what you desire is some data (e.g. text), then you don't need to know the `frameId` to send the data back tot he content script, you can just use the [`sendResponse`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#property-onMessage-sendResponse) function.

Content script:

```js
//Tell the background script to inject the additional script
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'sendTheData'}, function(response){
    doSomethingWithResponseData(response);
});
```

Background script:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(typeof message === 'object' && message.type === 'sendTheData') {
        sendResponse(theData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you...

Once the response is received by the CS, how does it insert or append the text/html into the chosen frame?

Comment: The data is sent only to the content script that has asked for it. In other words, the one that is running in the frame in which you desire for it to appear. You are going to have to deal with putting it into the DOM in some manner. A) There's not enough information in the question for us to know where you want it inserted. B) Including that in this question would make the question too broad. Questions should be relatively small problems which might be applicable to multiple people, not do this larger thing that is unique to my overall project, but which is a combination of medium sized steps.

Comment: @11treesWriting, It's quite reasonable to ask another question about that, and link to this one for additional information. However, please make an actual minimal, but complete **[mcve]**.  What is in the question is quite a bit more than minimal for this issue.

Comment: Got it - makes perfect sense and thank you for the guidance.

I do have a follow up question about your code...should I add to the original question with the working code that at least gets a console.log going on the dom (sent by executescript in background.js, as you suggest?). I don't see how to grab the frameId and I'm not sure the code is getting it.

Comment: Ah! I was using sender.tab.id.frameId to try and get the frameId...it's just sender.frameId. Will update and accept the question as answered. Not sure how we specify the ideal code...

Comment: @11treesWriting, [long response removed as it was invalidated by your next comment]. I'm still not fully clear on what you're wanting, so I've had a difficult time determining what would be ideal. Thus, this answer was not intended to be ideal, just to demonstrate how these two things could be done. I would fully expect that you will need to use something that is at least somewhat different from what's in this answer.